# How to copy contents within the child directory / folder?

Tags: php

I have a simple but a mind boggling problem.

I have a PHP code to create two directorires:

```
mkdir("uploads", 0777); // Create Folder
mkdir("uploads/input", 0777); // Create Folder
```

and the above code creates the said folder. Then I have another PHP code that copies an image file to *uploads/input* and the image is copied.

Likewise, I have upload.php a PHP code to copy files to Dropbox:

```
$dirtocopy = '/uploads/output/';
$dropboxdir = '/Public/backupdir/';
```

When I run the dropbox box code it doesn't copy */uploads/output/* and the error_log gives me the following:

```
PHP Warning:  opendir(/uploads/output/) [<a href='function.opendir'>function.opendir</a>]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home5/../upload.php on line 9
```

Though when I change `$dirtocopy = '/uploads/output/';` to `$dirtocopy = './';` It copies all the files in the parent except the folders!

I think my problem lies in `$dirtocopy`.

Thanks.

Comment: relative path should not start with `/`, or when it starts with `/` it must has dot(s)

Comment: `/uploads/output` is the equivalent of `c:\uploads\output`. if you have `uploads/output` (no leading slash), it'd be `c:\where\your\script\executes\uploads\output`.

Comment: I tried it it partially worked  but copied the files in uploads/output but not the **folders and their contents** within uploads/output

Comment: The error_log is telling me _'File 'uploads/output/yahoo' does not exist or is not readable.'_ when I manually change the permissions to 777 of all the files and directories within.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$dirtocopy = '/uploads/output/';
```

to

```
$dirtocopy = 'uploads/output/';
```

and it should work?

Comment: I tried it but it once again copied the files in uploads/output but not the folders within uploads/output.

Comment: The error_log is telling me _'File 'uploads/output/yahoo' does not exist or is not readable.'_ when I manually change the permissions to 777 of all the files and directories within.

Answer (score 0):

You only said you wanted to move images which are uploaded, not images stored in folders (I'm getting this impression).

You have a few options, and one is to loop through the directory name's in /uploads/input, create a new directory dynamically in the output folder, and then copy the files over. If needed (it sounds like it is) then copy the files in /uploads/input.

But this is complicated and also, you're working with user uploaded files here. What steps have you taken to prevent any security problems? Why are you dealing with both folders and pictures?

You should have 100% control over what is being submitted through the code, to avoid inconsistencies and to make it easier on yourself when it comes to this. I recommend taking full stock of what you're trying to do, then maybe send us an update with some more code.

Comment: How do I modify - $dirtocopy = '/uploads/output/'; include the folders withing, say $dirtocopy = '/uploads/output/folder1'; $dirtocopy = '/uploads/output/folder2'; $dirtocopy = '/uploads/output/folder3';